# iTextSharp to print GridView - output header width

Tags: asp.net, itext

I'm using iTextSharp to print a gridview, but facing a problem when trying to determine the appropriate width of the columns. In my gridview I don't set it, rather I let ASP.NET engine resize the widths (it does so dynamically based on the text's style).

By default, all the columns are of the same size which is bad in most cases.

How can I configure the header's PdfPCell object with a width suitable to the text in it?

Answer (score 0):

Column widths are calculated at the `PdfPTable` level so you'll need to address it there. Depending on which parser you are using there's a couple of ways to start this but the end result is that you need to parse your HTML into iTextSharp objects and then manually apply your own logic before committing them to the PDF. The code below is based on using the (preferred) XMLWorker and iTextSharp 5.4.0 as well as the following sample HTML:

```
<html>
   <head>
       <title>This is a test</title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <table>
           <thead>
               <tr>
                   <td>First Name</td>
                   <td>Last Name</td>
               </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
               <tr>
                   <td>Bob</td>
                   <td>Dole</td>
               </tr>
           </tbody>
       </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

First, you'll need to implement your own `IElementHandler` class. This will allow you to capture the elements before writing them to PDF.

```
Public Class CustomElementHandler
    Implements IElementHandler
    ''//List of all elements
    Public elements As New List(Of IElement)

    ''//Will get called for each top-level elements
    Public Sub Add(w As IWritable) Implements IElementHandler.Add
        ''//Sanity check
        If (TypeOf w Is WritableElement) Then
            ''//Add the element (which might have sub-elements)
            elements.AddRange(DirectCast(w, WritableElement).Elements)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then you just need to use your handler above instead of writing directly to the document:

```
''//TODO: Populate this with your HTML
Dim Html = ""
''//Where we're write our PDF to
Dim File1 = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "File1.pdf")
''//Create our PDF, nothing special here
Using FS As New FileStream(File1, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)
    Using Doc As New Document()
        Using writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc, FS)
            Doc.Open()

            ''//Create an instance of our handler
            Dim Handler As New CustomElementHandler()
            ''//Bind a StringReader to our text
            Using SR As New StringReader(Html)
                ''//Have the XMLWorker read our HTML and push it to our handler
                XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(Handler, SR)
            End Using

            ''//Loop through each element that the parser found
            For Each El In Handler.elements
                ''//If the element is a table
                If TypeOf El Is PdfPTable Then
                    ''//Below is just for illustration, change as needed

                    ''//Set the absolute width of the table
                    DirectCast(El, PdfPTable).TotalWidth = 500

                    ''//Set the first column to be 25% and the second column to be 75%
                    DirectCast(El, PdfPTable).SetWidths({0.25, 0.75})

                    ''//Also, just for illustration, turn borders on for each cell so that we can see the actual widths
                    For Each R In DirectCast(El, PdfPTable).Rows
                        For Each C In R.GetCells()
                            C.BorderWidthLeft = 1
                            C.BorderWidthRight = 1
                            C.BorderWidthBottom = 1
                            C.BorderWidthTop = 1
                        Next
                    Next
                End If

                ''//Add the element to the document
                Doc.Add(El)
            Next
            Doc.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```